# Implicit template argument is invalid, but compiles anyway

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, implicit-conversion

I have the following class:

```
class FunctionCallback
{
public:
    static CallbackHandle Create(const std::function<void(void)> &function);
    template<typename T,typename... TARGS>
        static CallbackHandle Create(const std::function<T(TARGS...)> &function);
};
```

I then call 'Create' like this:

```
FunctionCallback::Create<void,float>([](float f) -> void {}); // Whether I use a lambda-function or a function pointer makes no difference
```

Even though that should be correct (?), visual studio underlines that line in read with the message:

```
 Error: no instance of overloaded function "FunctionCallback::Create" matches the argument list
    argument types are: (lambda []void (float f)->void)
```

However the program **compiles** fine in visual studio without any warnings or errors.
g++-5 is unable to compile it altogether with a similar message.

When changing it to:

```
FunctionCallback::Create<void,float>(std::function<void(float)>([](float f) -> void {}));
```

It doesn't display the message anymore and compiles both on windows and linux.

Why can't it deduce the type properly unless I explicitly specify it?

Comment: Despite of the fact that vs.net was right or wrong about its predection of error. Do not depend on its messages before compiling when you are using templates.

Answer (score 0):

You almost never want to deduce the type of a type-eraser, that `std::function` is an example of. With a few exceptions, template type deduction attempts to deduce the exact type of an argument. For a `std::function<T>`-type parameter this means that the compiler can deduce `T` if the corresponding argument is a `std::function` as well. The type of a lambda expression is not a `std::function`.

Even if you explicitly specify type template arguments, the deduction still continues after corresponding types have been substituted with the arguments. In the case of a parameter pack, the compiler still tries to deduce the rest of arguments, so for `FunctionCallback::Create<void,float>` the compiler ends up with:

```
template <typename... TARGS>
static CallbackHandle Create(std::function<void(float, TARGS...)> function);
```

and this won't match anything else than `std::function<void(float, TARGS...)>` (or something that derives from this type); otherwise the deduction for `TARGS` fails.

If your goal is to always specify the parameter pack's types explicitly, you can put that pack (or the entire parameter) in a non-deduced context:

```
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };
template <typename T> using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;

struct FunctionCallback
{
    template <typename T, typename... TARGS>
    static void Create(identity_t<std::function<T(TARGS...)>> function);
};

FunctionCallback::Create<void, float>([](float f) -> void {});
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3a8b7f4edbbf624)

In this case, however, you'll have to pay the price of type-erasure. Instead, you can consider accepting any function object type:, letting the compiler to deduce the exact type of the argument:

```
struct FunctionCallback
{
    template <typename F>
    static void Create(F function){}
};

FunctionCallback::Create([](float f) -> void {});
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32766e541bfcf17b)